# How many sockets/plugs are allowed/recommended on a single gigabit ethernet link?

Tags: networking, ethernet

Consider this chain of wiring:

Switch (socket)
Patch cable (plugs)
Patch panel  (socket)
Solid core cable (hard wired at either end)
Wall socket (socket)
Long patch cable (plugs)
Wall socket (socket)
Solid core cable (hard wired at either end)
Wall socket (socket)
Patch cable (plugs)
Switch (socket)

This uses 5 runs of cable, joined via hardwired connections and plugs.

Is this likely to support a gigabit connection? (Assuming all components support Cat5e or better).

Comment: What's the total length?

Comment: I'm not sure, but let's assume it's ~20m.

Comment: Your setup is certainly not optimal. Simply "*assuming all components support Cat5e or better*" is not a good qualifier.  The installation & technique also matter. See https://www.truecable.com/blogs/cable-academy/ethernet-couplers-how-many-is-too-many#page_comments=1 What do you mean by "*Solid core cable (hard wired at either end)*" between a pair of wall sockets? "*Hard wired*"? You mean not soft wired? Not easy wired? Not wireless? Do the wall sockets have punch-downs? Or back-to-back receptacles aka coupler?

Comment: *Is this likely to support a gigabit connection* I'd give it a 50/50 chance - have you tried? you've got that abomination wired up, give it a go, you won't break anything by actually testing this yourself

Comment: So basically this is a bog-standard run, just with a jumper in the middle as you connect two segments. When you first try to parse this data as written it looks a lot, but any hardwired run uses three cables; two patch & one fixed. Its chances of working to a mere 20m are only slightly less than any run. Try it. Get an Ethernet tester if it doesn't work, to find the weak spot.

Comment: @JaromandaX LOL - I haven't built it yet, I'm trying to figure out if it's worth the hassle.

Comment: My apologies. I would say it's not worth the hassle if you're going to end up buying things for no reason. If you already have all those cables etc, then I would say try it :p

Comment: I appreciate all the comments, and I understand that no-one can give me a definitive yes/no on whether it will work. So instead, and just out of curiosity, I'll return to the title of my question: do the standards that govern ethernet cabling contain any restrictions on the number of sockets and plugs?